Проблема с установкой библиотеки libpq и установкой ее в visual studio
Я хочу поработать с бд Postgresql и c++, сделать пару легких проектов. Столкнулся со сложностями после питона))). В c++ библиотеку установить как по мне непросто( ну наверное мне пока непривычно). Так вот. Посмотрел пару гайдов, там нужно было скачать и распаковать папку с библиотекой. Я скачал видимо не с того сайта и у меня не было нескольких директорий и файлов , например dll и lib(была только папка, а файла с таким расширением не было). При установке этой библиотеки в visual studio у меня выдается ошибка LNK1104   не удается открыть файл "libpq.lib". Прошу Вас, помогите, пожалуйста, с пошаговой инструкцией установки, а также поделитесь сайтом откуда модно скачать библиотеку. Знаю, что для ответа на мой вопрос могут понадобиться пути PATH. И еще скажу на всякий случай, что я использую postgresql 14.11.

Поставьте лучше эту библиотеку из vcpkg.
